# FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap(); marca error

Tags: java, jsf

Estoy tratando de obtener un parámetro de la URL con

```
FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap();
```

Pero en esa parte del código me marca el siguiente error:

```
non static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

¿Cual seria la forma correcta de usar esa función? o ¿Existe alguna mejor manera de obtener parámetros de la URL en JSF (JavaServer Faces)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una manera de obtener los parámetros de la URL

http://localhost:8080/SoftMolina/page.jsf?parametroId=100

Parametro parametroId = valor 100.

1.- Debes agregar la etiqueta `<f:viewParam>` dentro de `<f:metadata>` ejemplo:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="parametroId" value="#{manageBean.parametroId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

El atributo manageBean.parametroId almacena el valor obtenido por URL.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head></h:head>
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="parametroId" value="#{manageBean.parametroId}"/>
</f:metadata>
<body>
 //Cuerpo...
</body>
</html>
```

Y Desde un ManageBean accediendo al contexto de la aplicación seria de la siguiente forma:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext. getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
Map params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
Integer almacenaParametroObtenido = new Integer((String) params.get("parametroId" ));
```